# Finding partial derivatives of critical points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the critical points of the function below. i have done the first derivative and later let $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)=0$. However i have only found 1 critical point when there are supposed to be 2. How do i get the other?

$$f(x,y)=e^x(2xy+y^2)$$
$$f_x(x,y)=2ye^x+e^x(2xy+y^2)$$
$$f_y(x,y)=2e^x(x+y)$$

Comment: How can you get only one? The natural process of finding one of the  critical points yields two of them at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**:

For $f_x(x,y)=e^x(2y+2xy+y^2)=0$. Therefore $y(2+2x+y)=0$. For $f_y(x,y)=2e^x(x+y)=0$. Therefore $x+y=0$

EDIT: If you need more help tell me how far you have got with these hints.

Comment: thanks i understood what went wrong. i removed the below term and thus i could only find one instead of two $$2e^x$$

Comment: The exponential term is not important in this expression as $e^x\neq 0\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: so i got the below term which i have to sub back into fx(x,y) $$x=1$$ and $$x+y$$

Comment: How did you achieve $x=1$? As if $x=1$ then $y=-1$ and then $f_x(x,y)\neq 0$

Comment: My bad, are these the right critical points? (0,0) and (2,-2)

Comment: Yes those are the points I found :)